# Partialy clip subviews

Tags: iphone, uiview, ipad

I am trying to get a UIView to clip to subviews but not entirely. I mean like an alpha change, outside the bounds

**Edit:**

I want this to be like the keynote `mask` feature for an image in the iPad.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't going to be able to change alpha outside the bounds of a view, as you indicate.  But a better solution would be:

Create a new view that extends the entire area.  Set the alpha of this view to the desired value.  Add another view inside this view, set clipsToBounds = YES on this view.

You can achieve this by using 2 views, but I don't think you can with 1.